# Calculating the peak of a gaussian curve from the area

Tags: integration, derivatives

I run an online service, and I'm trying to calculate the maximum number of users that we'll have online at any given time, given the following assumptions:

The total number of active users is 1000

Each user is online for 30 minutes

The times that the users are online range from 8:00 AM to 6:00 PM

The peak of the curve is 4 hours in, so 12:00 PM

How would I go about calculating the number of users from the area? I would try a derivative but I only know the area, not the function that models the curve.

From what I gather, normally you would need the standard deviation and maximum to solve for this, but in my case I'm trying to solve for the maximum.

Obviously the curve is asymptotic and doesn't ever equal zero, so I want it to cut off at something reasonable like 1%. Therefore the standard deviation is somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your description of your problem. You have the number of users as a function of time. Is it supposed to be a function of anything else, like some random fluctuation that you can't readily predict? What data do you have, exactly?

Comment: Hi Ian, the main issue is that I don't have enough data from user activity to accurately predict server costs and traffic throughout the day. I'm looking for the peak number of users because that will tell me how powerful the equipment has to be to support peak load, based off different numbers of active users, in this case 1,000. That's why this has to be a function of time. In my experience website load tends to fluctuate on a Gaussian curve, so that's why I'm using a Gaussian curve to model it. Of course it won't be a perfect model, but it will be more accurate than assuming a flat rate.